# How to host WAMP servers on multiple PCs in same network and allow access through external link?

Tags: apache, wampserver, httpd.conf

I have few PCs in same network. One of the machines (ip: 192.168.1.110) is already hosting a WAMP server which is accessible through an external IP. I now want to install WAMP server on one more machine (ip: 192.168.1.120) and make it accessible through external link. But this new machine is not getting accessed through external link. Is there any configuration related stuff that I need to do in httpd.conf file to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your idea of using a second PC running a second WAMPServer. Not that 2 machines and 2 WAMPServers is a problem.

First, I assume your router has already had port 80 "Port Forwarded" to the original PC's IpAddress  (ip: 192.168.1.110). It cannot be forwarded to 2 different internal IP addresses, unless you tell people to use a different port number for the second sites domain name so that you can forward that other port to your second PC's port 80.

This leaves you a couple of possibilities :-

You either setup the original PC's Apache as a Proxy for the second PC and therefore forward accesses for the second site to the second PC while still running the first site on the first PC

Or, more simply in my opinion you stay with One PC running WAMPServer and you make use of Apache's `Virtual Hosts` capabilities.

This way as long as you have 2 seperate domain names, both pointing to your Routers WAN IP address both can still use port 80 i.e. Users dont need to add a port number. Apache will decide what site is required and run that site by simply looking at the domain name and redirecting everything to the right place.

[See this post for some help on how to setup Virtual Hosts in WAMPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Its should only take a few minutes to setup.